# Retrieving the record by Primary Key is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Table Schema**

```
Create Table User
(
    UserID int,
    FirstName varchar(50)
)
```

**User Model**

```
class User_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "user";
}
```

**Below is my code in Laravel 5**

```
$users = \App\Models\User_Model::find(1);
```

**Error Message**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.id' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user` where `user`.`id` = 1 limit
>   1)

Comment: Can you please paste the output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE user" from the database?

Comment: Do you want to check the Table Schema ?

Comment: I'm curious to know if the column truly exists, or perhaps your table's name is actually "users" instead of "user"

Comment: Laravel is saying : user.id and My primary key is UserID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've updated your table name, you also need to set the primary key you're using as it's not the assumed `id` field

```
class User_Model extends Model
{ 
    protected $table = "user";
    protected $primaryKey = "UserID";
}
```